# What are the possible characters for a German passport number?

Tags: passports, german-citizens

My German passport number contains an O (letter) or 0 (number), but I cannot tell which one. Is there a list of characters that are used for German passport numbers, or more concretely, can someone tell me which character is shown below?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sometimes you can work it out on the machine readable row or if still there a sticker which was put on when they made it for you. On my passport they used a different font and the difference between O and 0 was easier to see.

Comment: @Willeke my thought exactly. The machine readable font is actually specified by the standard, and the two characters are fairly distinct, so one can compare very easily.

Comment: Never blur information to hide it. Always use opaque boxes. [Blurring can be reversed](https://dheera.net/projects/blur).

Comment: @andynitrox Did you just change a set of blurred pictures with another set of blurred pictures?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev oha. I must have misread the previous comment. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Passport "number"

Comment: You may want to delete the old image versions from imgur as well, they're still there, and being accessible (in a sense of "publicly visible") via the "edited 2 hours ago" link.

Comment: @andynitrox if you really worried about someone reversing the blurring and finding out the number, you should flag the question for moderator attention and explain. They could edit and remove the images from the revision history.

Comment: Wow. Not only do they confusingly use letters as well as numbers, but also they use a font in which the glyph for zero looks like what most fonts would use as an upper-case letter O.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you trust [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_passport), it's a zero. I can't get any more specific with sourcing, as my German is pretty poor and I can't go through the sources listed.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to add that an official source (bmi.bund.de) supports this. All letters except for vowels and B, D, Q and S are used to avoid the formation of words and to ensure everything is machine readable.

Comment: @WGroleau please read what andy said: vowels are not used so it can only be a 0. Apparently numbers are more important than letters.

Comment: Ha, guess I should delete that comment!  (I once worked in an office where I frequently had to call someone up to find out "Is this a 'G' or a '6'?")

Answer (score 59):

To quote the [*Verordnung zur Durchführung des Passgesetzes (Passverordnung – PassV)*](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/passv_2007/BJNR238610007.html), the regulation for the implementation of the passport law:

> ### Anlage 11 Formale Anforderungen an die Einträge in Pässe im Sinne des § 1 Absatz 2 des Passgesetzes
>
> […]
>
> 9. Die alphanumerische Seriennummer des Reisepasses, Dienstpasses und Diplomatenpasses wird ausschließlich aus den Buchstaben C, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, R, T, V, W, X, Y, Z und den Ziffern 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 gebildet. Beim Kinderreisepass, vorläufigen Reisepass, vorläufigen Dienstpass und vorläufigen Diplomatenpass besteht die Seriennummer aus einem Serienbuchstaben und sieben Ziffern.

Translated:

> ### Appendix 11: formal requirements of the entries in passports according to § 1 section 2 of the passport law
>
> […]
>
> 9. The alphanumeric serial number of a passport, an official passport and a diplomatic passport is formed exclusively with the letters C, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, R, T, V, W, X, Y, Z and the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. The serial number of a child’s passport, preliminary passport, preliminary official passport or a preliminary diplomatic passport consists of a serial letter and seven digits.

Thus, the letter `O` (Oh) is not used and it can only be a digit `0` (zero).

Comment: Last line is it letter '0' or 'O'? My eyes are not good at this time of the day.

Comment: @vasin1987 Well, I personally would never refer to zero as a letter. Also, that’s why it’s held in monospace because monospace fonts typically differentiate by slashing the zero.

Comment: @Jan in my browser, the SO "normal text" proportional font renders O and 0 very distinctly (owing in part, I presume, to their different widths).  The "code sample" monospace font renders the two characters so similarly that I cannot tell them apart unless they are immediately adjacent to one another. I am only familiar with a couple of monospace fonts that slash or dot the zero. Most seem not to.

Comment: @Jan unfortunately imprecise use of "letter" and "digit" to mean "character" is not particularly unusual. (Courier actually doesn't slash the zero, nor does Courier New; I don't know why you would think they do.)

Comment: @phoog You’re correct … this is why I should never trust my brain. Anyhoo, the (zero) has been there from the time of writing at the end of the line; I wouldn’t know how to add more clarity without losing brevity …

Comment: I think the german passport number is a good example of bad typography.

Comment: I imagine the conversation in the ministry went something like this. 1) "Oh darn, the 0 and the O look very similar in this font. Hans, what should we do??" 2) "Karl, I know just the solution. If we *only* use 0 then everyone can logically exclude that it is a O" 3) "Hans, that's perfect! Let's go and write this up and then we publish it on the website as additional information: problem solved!"

Comment: 4) A few weeks later another Ministerialbeamter enters the room and goes "Hey guys, why don't we cut out *both* the 0 and the O? Then we avoid the issue altogether!" 5) "Oh no, don't be ridiculous. Everyone can solve this problem by simple logic!" And as a result an estimated ~10 Million Germans have to look up the stupid information on the BMI website every time they have to enter their passport 'number'... Well done Ministry of the Interior, well done. [I will add a 'slow cap' in my head.]